# NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm new to rails, and I am not sure how to proceed. I'm trying to complete the "RailsSpace" book but am running into errors in the section about testing.  (page 119 for anyone that may have the book)

Rails 3.2.8

ruby 1.9.3p194

When running this in console:

```
@error_messages = ActiveRecord::Errors.default_error_messages; 0
```

I get this error:

**NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors**

when running `rake test:units`

I get:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/config/environment.rb:5)
Run options: 


# Running tests:

EEEEE

Finished tests in 0.108070s, 46.2663 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_screen_name_maximum_length(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
    /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'

  2) Error:
test_screen_name_minimum_length(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
    /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'

  3) Error:
test_uniqueness_of_screen_name_and_email(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
    /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'

  4) Error:
test_user_invalidity(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
    /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'

  5) Error:
test_user_validity(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Errors
    /Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'

5 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 5 errors, 0 skips
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (5): [/Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bi...]

Tasks: TOP => test:units
```

My **user_test.rb** file looks like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase


  def setup 
    @error_messages = ActiveRecord::Errors.default_error_messages
    @valid_user = users(:valid_user)
    @invalid_user = users(:invalid_user)
  end

  #This user should be valid by construction.
  def test_user_validity
    assert @valid_user.valid?
  end

  #This user should be invalid by construction.
  def test_user_invalidity
    assert !@invalid_user.valid?
    attributes = [:screen_name, :email, :password]
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      #assert @invalid_user.errors.invalid?(attribute) OLD CODE DOES NOT WORK IN RAILS3
       assert @invalid_user.invalid?(attribute)
    end
  end

  def test_uniqueness_of_screen_name_and_email
    user_repeat = User.new( :screen_name => @valid_user.screen_name,
                            :email       => @valid_user.email,
                            :password    => @valid_user.password)
    assert !user_repeat.valid?
    assert_equal @error_messages[:taken], user_repeat.errors.on(:screen_name)
    assert_equal @error_messages[:taken], user_repeat.errors.on(:email)

  end

  #MAKE SURE THE SCREEN NAME CAN'T BE TO SHORT
  def test_screen_name_minimum_length
    user = @valid_user
    min_length = User::SCREEN_NAME_MIN_LENGTH

    #Screen name is too short.
    user.screen_name = "a" * (min_length - 1)
    assert !user.valid?, "#{user.screen_name} should raise a minimum length error"
    #Format the error message based on minimum length.
    correct_error_message = sprintf(@error_messages[:too_short], min_length)
    assert_equal correct_error_message, user.errors.on(:screen_name)

    #Screen name is minimum length.
    user.screen_name = "a" * min_length
    assert user.valid?, "#{user.screen_name} should be just long enough to pass"
  end

  #MAKE SURE THE SCREEN NAME CAN'T BE TOO LONG
  def test_screen_name_maximum_length
      user = @valid_user
      max_length = User::SCREEN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH

      # Screen name is too long.
      user.screen_name = "a" * (min_length + 1)
    assert !user.valid?, "#{user.screen_name} should raise a maximum length error"
    #Format the error message based on maximum length.
    correct_error_message = sprintf(@error_messages[:too_long], max_length)
    assert_equal correct_error_message, user.errors.on(:screen_name)

    #Screen name is maximumlength.
    user.screen_name = "a" * max_length
    assert user.valid?, "#{user.screen_name} should be just short enough to pass"
  end
end
```

According to the error message **"/Users/home/rails_projects/retrospection/test/unit/user_test.rb:7:in `setup'"** The line causing the problem is

```
@error_messages = ActiveRecord::Errors.default_error_messages
```

Comment: The Railspace is out of date. You can go to [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) and see something different with your code, then you can know what errors are.

Comment: I've already finished the Rails Tutorial, but I still don't feel like I have a good grasp on Rails. I thought I'd try to go through RailsSpace and complete my own updated Rails3 version of it. I think I'll just skip the section on testing since it is out of date, and see if I can continue through the rest of the book. I'll try to do testing the way it is done in the online Rails Tutorial.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. You have learnt Rails 3.x, you should keep learning about it, not the older version. The best way to understand Rails is building an app, a real app. You can build any app you like, when you do it, you will learn more and more, and you will understand about it. I'm also finished Rails Tutorial, and now i'm building an online test app for my graduation project at university, and when i built it, i recognized i have learnt many things and understood about it more than before.